# How do you place an element a fixed distance from the top of the browser even if the element is wrapped within multiple containers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an element which is inside an iframe. I want to place that element at a certain pixel distance from the top of the browser window. I am using 'top:XXpx' to set the distance but it doesn't seem to work. Looks like 'top' property calculates the distance from the immediate parent. Is there a way to set the distance from the top of the browser window despite the no. of containers the particular element is wrapped within ?

Comment: You should read up on [positioning contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#positioning_contexts).

Comment: Note that an element inside an iframe will not know the offset of that iframe from the parent window. You'll need to use JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it `position:absolute` first before using the top element.

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px; (or 50%)
```

Comment: Please don't use answers for meta-commentary. If a question lacks something, downvote the question, and do not answer it (otherwise, why will the user bother with adding code to their next question -- they get answers either way).

Comment: This answer ignores the crux of the problem which is that the element is inside an iframe, which could be positioned anywhere in relation to the top of the viewport.